# NavigationMixin Page Reference throwing error

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagereference

I've been at this for a few hours. I'm using JS directly from official Lightning documentation. I've added my custom LWC to Lightning Builder, and I'm getting the following error.

In the JS below, I've also tried isolating to 1 function. Each function fails with same error on its own.

[image]
[image]
----

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class EsrmHomePageNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  recordPageUrl;

  navigateToObjectHome() {
      // Navigate to the Account home page
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
          type: 'standard__objectPage',
          attributes: {
              objectApiName: 'Account',
              actionName: 'home',
          },
      });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    // Generate a URL to a User record page
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: '--I have a real ID here--',
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    }).then(url => {
        this.recordPageUrl = url;
    });
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-bottom_medium">
    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small slds-m-bottom_small">
        Home Page
    </h2>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Brand" title="Primary action" onclick={navigateToObjectHome} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Brand" title="Primary action" onclick={navigateToObjectHome} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Brand" title="Primary action" onclick={navigateToObjectHome} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Brand" title="Primary action" onclick={navigateToObjectHome} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to import `LightningElement`

`import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';`

Comment: Haha, 3 hours wasted on something so simple :) That's programming sometimes. Thanks a lot glls!

Comment: i know that feeling. happy to help!